# How to Convert Date to Int?

Tags: java, variables, int, simpledateformat

I'm Trying to get the current day value (example. 12) the assign it to a variable (example. today= 12).

```
        DateFormat DateFormat= new SimpleDateFormat ("dd");

        //get current day time with Date()
        Date day= new Date ();

        int day1 = Integer.valueOf(day);
```

Or

```
        DateFormat DateFormat= new SimpleDateFormat ("dd");

        //get current day time with Date()
        Date day= new Date ();

        int day1 = day;
```

Comment: Welcome to SO. Please provide some details to let us know what the problem is. What doesn't work? Why? What did you expect to happen? And what's happening instead?

Comment: first you need to learn how to debug your code ,this site is not a debuger sit

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
String year1= String.valueOf (year);
String month1= String.valueOf(month);
String day1= String.valueOf(day);
```

must be changed to

```
String year1= String.valueOf (num1);
String month1= String.valueOf(num2);
String day1= String.valueOf(num3);
```

because these 3 variables only hold the values entered by the user.

Also, not sure why you need the `hour`, because you never get that as inout from the user. In your case, what you've done for all these is use the `new Date()` as such which is throwing the exception.

The max you can do with your hour field is this

```
String hour1 = DateFormat3.format(hour); // Use the current time's hour value as you don't get any from user.
```

**Side Note:-** You can use a single SimpleDateFormat, single Scanner, and a lot of other optimizations, but that comes later, after you fix your code and logic.

Comment: As a side note, the OP is declaring a different scanner for each input, which is not needed. One scanner can be used to perform all inputs

Answer (score 0):

One thing which is obviously wrong is the way you use `DateFormat`. Its purpose is to format an instant in time as a date/time, so just one `DateFormat` is enough to render the full date, for example as YYYY/MM/DD.

Instead of asking the user for three separate entries, ask him to enter the full date in some format and define an appropriate `DateFormat` object to parse it into an instant. Here you're basically reimplementing that by hand.

Comment: As a side note, the OP is declaring a different scanner for each input, which is not needed. One scanner can be used to perform all inputs

Comment: You can - it's not generally appropriate to then recombine the values, but it's entirely fine to format "just the month" or "just the year" though.

Comment: @JonSkeet Yes, but only if you have an instant in your hand which you'll format. You can't have the number, say 11, and expect `DateFormat` to render it into a locale-specific month string.

Comment: @MarkoTopolnik: Sure, I completely agree on that front.